# Integral with exponential function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, integral-equations

Could you please help me in solving the following integration. Thank you in advance.

Integrate[((Sqrt[g*(x + h)/y])^V) * Exp[-u * Sqrt[g*(x + h)/y]/n] * Exp[-L*x], {x, 0, Infinity}]

[image]

Comment: if you can integrate $\int x^n e^{-x^2-x}  \, dx$ then you might have a chance of integrating your integral.  Not all integrals can be integrated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assumed the parameters are positive real numbers.  One could simplify things a little by replacing `g/y` by `a` and `u/n` by `b` — the more parameters, the harder you make it for Mathematica.

`Integrate` evaluates in the special case `h = 0`, but not for other values of `h` tested.

```
Clear[g, L, x, h, y, V, n, u];
Block[{h = 0},
 Integrate[((Sqrt[g*(x + h)/y])^V)*Exp[-u*Sqrt[g*(x + h)/y]/n]*
   Exp[-L*x], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> V > 0 && g > 0 && u > 0 && n > 0 && L > 0 && y > 0]
 ]
(*
(2^(-1 - V) ((L y)/g)^(-V/2)
  Gamma[2 + V] HypergeometricU[1 + V/2, 1/2, (g u^2)/(4 L n^2 y)])/L
*)
```

It evaluates if only `V` is given numeric values (in all tests):

```
Block[{g, h, V = 3, L, n, u, y},
 Integrate[((Sqrt[g*(x + h)/y])^V)*Exp[-u*Sqrt[g*(x + h)/y]/n]*
   Exp[-L*x], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> 
   V > 0 && g > 0 && u > 0 && n > 0 && L > 0 && y > 0 && h > 0]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The remaining cases probably cannot be done.

Comment: This is strange. Why does Mathematica integrate the definite integral but not the indefinite one? ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjRJz.png)  I am using V 12.3. I always start with the indefinite case, and if that works, only then I try the definite integral.

Comment: @Nasser There are methods available for definite integrals, for example, [contour integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration), that are not available for indefinite ones.